# Google App Engine dedicated memcache in 1.8.9

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

We are using *dedicated* memcache, it was running correctly until yesterday. Now we can see lots of theese entries in log :

```
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.LogAndContinueErrorHandler handleServiceError: Service error in memcache
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache get: exception getting 1 key 
...
```

If I switch back to *Shared memcache*, everything works fine.

Maybe it can be connected to app engine 1.8.9, because all our instances are using this version ( from yesterday ). Application is written in Java and we are using 4GB of *dedicated* memcache.

Comment: Today we experienced the memcache problem, too.  Google rolled back to 1.8.8.